# Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page and Get Profile Images of the Users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I was looking out the solutions but no luck for getting the list the users who likes your Facebook page. I found out the following solutions over internet but all have some limitations. Please suggest??

1. Facebook provides like table where we can provide object name to get the list of users who likes your Album,Photo etc. But I didn't find to get this work for a Facebook Page. It is working for photo,album etc.
2. Second options with page_fan table but i notice that only the uid field is index able so you need to know the user id to search it and not the page_id.
3. Finally i added the Like Box in my applications where I am showing the list of user with their profile picture but here is also limitation with face book like box that i can't see the entire list of the users who likes the Facebook Page. It is showing only 20-30 in the Like Box. If i was trying to change the iFrame div CSS to overflow:auto but their is no success because i think iFrame with other domain url doesn't allow the same.

Can someone help me out how i can get the all Facebook User's profile photos who likes my Facebook page with any 3 options or let me know if any other options.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I would like to do a div background with images of the folks who liked a page, but am not sure where to begin (OpenGraph, API, etc.).